# How to implement BFS in Java using a queue (Intro to Algorithms HW)?

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm, data-structures, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to implement the BFS algorithm in Java using the following pseudocode:

```
1.   for each vertex u ∈ G.V - {s}  // for each vertex except for the source
2.       u.color = WHITE            // (line 1 cont) in the graph
3.       u.distance = ∞
4.       u.parent = NIL
5.   source.color = GRAY
6.   source.distance = 0
7.   source.parent = NIL
8.   Q = Ø
9.   Enqueue (Q, source)
10.  while Q != Ø
11.      u = Dequeue(Q)
12.      for each v ∈ G.Adj[u]              // for each adjacent vertext
13.            if v.color == WHITE
14.                  v.color = GRAY         
15.                  v.distance = u.distance + 1
16.                  v.parent = u
17.                  Enqueue(Q, v)
18.      u.color = BLACK
```

The colors represent each time that node has been visited:

1. **WHITE = 2** is undiscovered
2. **GRAY = 3** is discovered, but its adjacent neighbors have not all been discovered
3. **BLACK = 4** is discovered, all adjacent neighbors discovered, no need to return here

u.distance represents the distance from the node to the source node, and u.parent is the parent that leads back to the source node

My professor said rather than creating an object for each node (u.color, u.d, u.pi), we should instead use an array for each to store the values for each node.

He also provided us with the skeleton code which includes an adjacency matrix to test it on.

--

**I'm currently struggling with lines 11 and 12** (I think).  I am able to create and initialize all the arrays as well as the queue, but I am having trouble implementing the **queue.poll()** or **queue.remove()** function in **line 11** to act as I expect.  I also don't know if I'm creating the for loop correctly.

I tried using the .poll() and .remove() functions imported from LinkedList and Queue.  **What this SHOULD do is remove the head of the queue and assign its value to the variable u, no?**

**When I run my code, line 17 adds to the queue, but the head of the queue is never removed in the next iteration, and line 18 only executes on the first iteration (the source node).**

I am not sure if I am implementing **line 12** of the pseudocode properly as I'm using a normal for-loop (int v; v < n; v++) but I've seen other examples do something like: for (Integer v : graph.adj[u]), but I don't know how to properly implement that or find the package for the .adj() method.

```
while (!q.isEmpty())
        {
            u = q.poll();                           // sets value of u... to most recent item removed from queue??
            for (v = 0; v < colors.length; v++)                 
            {
                if (colors[v] == WHITE)
                {
                    colors[v] = GRAY;               // Sets color of VISITED Node to 

                    dist[v] = dist[u] + 1;      // sets distance at index v to value of the index most recently removed from queue + 1                  
                    parent[v] = u;                  // sets  parent of index v to most recently removed item from queue                 
                    q.add(v);                       // adds node V to the queue
                }
            }
            colors[u] = BLACK;                  // sets color of node to black (node visited + adjacent nodes visited)

        }

        return dist;                                // returns distance array

    }
```

I try to print out the arrays along the way to see how the for loop is operating.  Using this code, I can see that the head is not being removed from the queue and assigned to the value u after the first iteration.

Here is the matrix it is being tested on:

```
        int n = 8;
        int[][] A = 
            {{0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
            {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0},
            {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1},
            {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
            {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
            {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}};
```

MY RESULTS:

```
COLORS: [2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
DISTANCE: [2147483647, 0, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647]
PARENT: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

COLORS: [3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
dist[u] = 0
DISTANCE: [1, 0, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647]
PARENT: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
QUEUE: []

COLORS: [3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
dist[u] = 0
DISTANCE: [1, 0, 1, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647]
PARENT: [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
QUEUE: [0]

COLORS: [3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2]
dist[u] = 0
DISTANCE: [1, 0, 1, 1, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647]
PARENT: [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
QUEUE: [0, 2]

COLORS: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2]
dist[u] = 0
DISTANCE: [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647]
PARENT: [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
QUEUE: [0, 2, 3]

COLORS: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2]
dist[u] = 0
DISTANCE: [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2147483647, 2147483647]
PARENT: [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
QUEUE: [0, 2, 3, 4]

COLORS: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2]
dist[u] = 0
DISTANCE: [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2147483647]
PARENT: [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
QUEUE: [0, 2, 3, 4, 5]

COLORS: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
dist[u] = 0
DISTANCE: [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
PARENT: [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
QUEUE: [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I expect it to be something at the end like the following:

```
COLORS: [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
dist[u] = most recently removed from queue (not 0)
DISTANCE: [1, 0, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3]
QUEUE: []
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't have `return dist;` inside the `while (!q.isEmpty())` loop. Or is that just bad indentations on your part?

Comment: `for each v ∈ G.Adj[u]` is not written correctly, because your `v` loop is not using `u` at all, i.e. is not "for each adjacent vertext".

Comment: the ```return dist;``` line was a miswriting on my part.  It's not in the while loop in the actual code.  How would you write the for loop?  I see the way I've implemented it doesn't make any sense but I'm not really sure how else to do so (in Java)?

Comment: I do not see `G.Adj[u]`  (get neighbors) in your code. For more help please post your code, not just the snippet posted. See [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The for loop inside your while loop is incorrect. Since you are given an adjacency matrix representation, let Graph[][] be the matrix, you have the following property.

Graph[i][j] == 0, there is no edge between vertex i and j;
Graph[i][j] == 1, there is an edge between vertex i and j;

Say you have n vertices, the for loop should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(Graph[u][i] == 1) {
        //put in the color/distance updates here
    }
}
```

The other examples you mentioned(Integer v : graph.adj[u]) is an adjacency list representation of a graph.